# How to pass dynamic roles to Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Standard way of defining an Ansible playbook with roles is:

```
--- 
- hosts: webservers 
  roles:
    - common 
    - webservers
```

I would like to pass a single command line variable for the Ansible role. I mean to say there should be a single Ansible role which would be a variable and I should be able to pass the choice of role (common or webserver) from outside.

Please let me know if and how we can achieve this:

```
roles:
  - {{ choice }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) in *play.yml*

```
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ choice }}"
```

and run it

```
# ansible-playbook -e "choice=common" play.yml
```