# How to pass variable values to roles in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to pass the values to roles from the input which im getting from `vars_prompt`.
Kindly advise is it possible or not.

```
-name: Topic creation
 hosts: all
 vars_prompt:
  - name: environment
    prompt: "Enter the environment"
    private: no
 roles:
  - "{{ environmet }}"
```

When i run the playbook getting an error.
`Error! environment is undefined`

Kindly advise how to pass the value to roles.

Want to pass the values to roles.

Comment: Is the syntax error `environmet` != `environment` intentionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand that corerct the error you are observing is usually because of the variable initialization difference between compile time and runtime.

According the error message

```yaml
 roles:
  - "{{ environment }}"
```

would be resolved during compile time and before the prompting for the environment during runtime.

```yaml
 vars_prompt:
  - name: environment
    prompt: "Enter the environment"
    private: no
```

You may also have a look into further documentation about

- [`import_role` module – Import a role into a play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html)
- [`include_role` module – Load and execute a role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html)

  > *Dynamically loads and executes a specified role as a task.*
- [What's the difference between `include_` and `import_`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)

This means you would need to change the way you are referencing the role or providing the name for it. See a

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to pass dynamic roles to Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55719844/6771046)